# Issues with Cisco IPSec VPN speed. Fast uploads, slow downloads from external to internal servers

Tags: linux-networking, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn, iperf

We are using a Cisco ASA5516, configured with a IPsec (IKEv1) split tunnel VPN.

When uploading files to a server behind the firewall, the transfer speeds are normal (up to 10mbps).

When downloading files from the server, it's sitting around 100kbps (starts a little higher then drops).

I have tried changing the MTU for both internal and external interfaces on the firewall from 1500 to 1400, and 1360, but this makes no difference.

Performing traceroute from my machine to a server behind the firewall, it's showing a single hop.

Performing traceroute from the server behind the firewall to my machine, it's showing a single hop.

Using iperf3, i'm getting an average of 10Mbps from my machine to the server, and from the server to my machine, it's an average of about 300kbps.

I've also tried server to server behind the firewall, and it's averaging about 50Mbps.

Something just doesn't seem right, and i'm out of ideas.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, have you done speed tests with regular traffic outside your VPN tunnel to ensure it isn't something with your internet service?

Comment: Have tried these tests from two different locations, both getting 50Mbps down, and over 5Mbps up when doing a speed test.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a problem with the data centre rather than our configuration.
They had set our connections to be 100mbps half duplex rather than 1gbps full duplex.